# Read and Write the MetaData contents as a File in Documents Directory

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-drive-api, metadata

```
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString* arrayText = [MetaDataArray componentsJoinedByString: @"\n"];

    NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"EmployeeData.txt"];

    [arrayText writeToFile:path atomically:YES];
```

**MetaData Array first Object look like this :**

```
    {fileSize:"9385033" labels:{viewed,starred,restricted,trashed,hidden} 
originalFilename:"Chamak Challo - Ra.One (2011) [MP3-320Kbps-CBR].mp3" mimeType:"audio/mpeg" 
title:"Chamak Challo - Ra.One (2011) [MP3-320Kbps-CBR].mp3" parents:[1] 
md5Checksum:"51d598c750102dd4bca09addf4d8212d" quotaBytesUsed:"9385033" 
lastModifyingUserName:"shadow.hibrise" copyable?:1 
headRevisionId?:"0B7v4X9XjauwJR3dZM1FQWlpHeEFOZGYyYzR2NUdtLzhmb2FNPQ" kind:"drive#file" 
writersCanShare:1 appDataContents?:0 modifiedDate:"2014-03-04T11:13:32.649Z" shared?:0 
id:"0B7v4X9XjauwJdTUyeW5zTVRNTU0" ownerNames:[1] userPermission:{etag,kind,id,type,role}
 createdDate:"2014-03-04T11:13:32.649Z" fileExtension:"mp3" 
iconLink?:"https://ssl.gstatic.com/docs/doclist/images/icon_10_audio_list.png" 
modifiedByMeDate:"2014-03-04T11:13:32.634Z" downloadUrl:"https://doc-10-3s-
docs.googleusercontent.com/docs/securesc/0ijvatgpdej0qafpk7qtp7n2jgndtb3d/ifb42us5ai6ae9ah4kalfu4cnrtl6j3n/1398153600000/18240796891762319987/18240796891762319987/0B7v4X9XjauwJdTUyeW5zTVRNTU0?h=16653014193614665626&e=download&gd=true" lastModifyingUser?:{kind,displayName,permissionId,isAuthenticatedUser} editable:1 etag:""fgLq6vWOgR-hiHy-psxfsLtIDgQ/MTM5MzkzMTYxMjY0OQ"" webContentLink:"https://docs.google.com/uc?id=0B7v4X9XjauwJdTUyeW5zTVRNTU0&export=download" owners?:[1] alternateLink:"https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B7v4X9XjauwJdTUyeW5zTVRNTU0/edit?
usp=drivesdk"}
```

I want to store Array of Objects as a file and vice versa.

Comment: Based on your comments to suggested solutions, it's not completely clear what you want to do.  You have some file metadata that comprises your object graph; and you wish to persist that graph somehow, correct?  The objects in `MetaDataArray` look like raw JSON.  Surely, you don't want to save the raw unparsed JSON...

Comment: https://gist.github.com/vksaini13/11174344

Answer (score 1):

You can use Sqllite or core data instead of filesystem.

For core-data please refer this [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdUsingPersistentStores.html)

For filesystem [this](http://www.raywenderlich.com/1914/nscoding-tutorial-for-ios-how-to-save-your-app-data) can be useful

Comment: I need to take one by one metadata. its processing time was bit high :) if i save it as file its a single process to save. So i don't want complicate it.